# Maintaining session object in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

What I am attempting to do is preserve a session object that stores a Dictionary .

I need this dictionary in order to keep a running list that matches up to an asp:Gridview.

Every time the page loads, I'm checking the Dictionary and highlighting any matches in the Gridview.

However, every time Page_Load occurs, the Session["Rolls"] is coming up as null. Now, I'm also highlighting matching entries in a buttonClick event and the Dictionary is preserved up until I initiate a different event (like another button click OR GridView_RowEditing/GridView_RowUpdating). Are there any principals of Session variables that I'm not paying attention to?

Google Chrome console also recognizes the Session throughout every action, but in Debug, every Page_Load brings up a null Session["Rolls"].

Here's my Page_Load code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["Rolls"] = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }
        else
        {
            WoSource.SelectCommand =
            "SELECT WorkOrderNo, RollNumber, ModelNumber, QtyGood, QtyRun FROM RFID_Inventory WHERE WorkOrderNo= '" + woText.Text + "'";

            var currentDict = (Dictionary<string, int>) Session["Rolls"];
            if (currentDict == null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var entry in currentDict)
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        var dataKey = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex];
                        if (dataKey != null && (dataKey["RollNumber"].ToString() == entry.Key && entry.Value == 0))
                        {
                            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (dataKey != null && (dataKey["RollNumber"].ToString() == entry.Key && entry.Value == 1))
                        {
                            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Discovered that the RowEditing/RowUpdating events are not preserving the GridView Backcolor highlighting that I'm doing.

Is there something I can add to those event calls?

Here is my RowEditing event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentDict = (Dictionary<string, int>)Session["Rolls"];
        if (currentDict == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var entry in currentDict)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    var dataKey = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex];
                    if (dataKey != null && (dataKey["RollNumber"].ToString() == entry.Key && entry.Value == 0))
                    {
                        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (dataKey != null && (dataKey["RollNumber"].ToString() == entry.Key && entry.Value == 1))
                    {
                        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT2:** My issue was solved. My session wasn't coming back null. I actually needed to add my GridView highlighting method to the GridView_RowDataBound event. Turns out I was just trying to highlight the gridview at the wrong time. I marked the Kishore's answer as correct so that users can see my reply. Thanks for everybody's help.

Comment: beware of sql injection in your sql query

Comment: is that something to worry about on a local web app?

Comment: best practice is to always be safe, you never know what could happen. what if that code is reuse in another web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i look your code you are initialize session variable on page load so you lost the state. you can put a null check before initialize session variable.

Comment: Well that's only on the first Page_Load. Every event calls a postback which is checked in Page_Load. I don't need to preserve the Session after a person leaves the page.

Comment: Its Ok. Where you fill the data in session variable?

Comment: Alright I've discovered the issue. I added my GridView highlighting method to the event GridView_RowDataBound and that solved my issue. I'm going to mark your answer as correct so users see this. Thank you for help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well What we do for managing our Global Object into session is Encapsulating them in Property. Lets have a look in this:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Rolls
{
   get 
   {
       if(Session["Rolls"] == null) 
           return new Dictionary<string, int>();
       else
           return (Dictionary<string, int>)Session["Rolls"];
   }

   set
   {
      Session["Rolls"] = value;
   }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Now Accessing Rolls in page will be directly hitting Session.
   // and Get property will give New dictionary object with 0 record instead of null
   // Otherwise it will return Object already caste into dictionary object

   foreach (var entry in Rolls) 
   {

   }

   // We always can assign new Dictionary object in Session by
   Rolls = new Dictionary<string, int>(10); // for example dictionary with 10 items
}
```

So we can use our Get Set in Parent class of Web page to make it accessible on all child classes. We can use similar approaches for View state and Cache objects as well.

Let me know if you have any question.